# How to change the header and spacing in Europasscv?

Tags: spacing, header-footer, line-spacing, cv, europasscv

I am using europasscv format for my CV and I wanted to adjust a few things in it. This is the example CV in overleaf:

[image]

How can I move my name on the top where Curriculum vita is written just in the first page and then reduce the space between address, phone number, etc at the beginning of the cv?

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=hyphen,sorting=none,style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography}

\bibliography{europasscv_example}
% in the bibliography, mark all occurrences in bold:
\ecvbibhighlight{Smith}{Katie}{K.}

\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
% \ecvgithubpage{www.github.com/smith}
% \ecvgitlabpage{www.gitlab.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
% \ecvorcid[label, link]{0000-0000-0000-0000}
\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}
```

Comment: The europass is a predefined formular you should not change in layout. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @Mensch I know. I like the general format of this CV but I want to change a lit bit of small details if it is possible.